# Is parentheses after $_GET['function_name'] allowed? --> $_GET['function_name']();?

Tags: php, function, url, get, parentheses

Is this code allowed? -> `$_GET['function_name']` then (). When combined it will look like this: `$_GET['function_name']();`

Here's what I was trying to do:

I have a function:

```
function a() {
echo "A";
}
```

When I go to this URL:
[www.myurl.com/?id=page1&function_name=a](http://www.myurl.com/?id=page1&function_name=a)

I want to get the function name from the URL so:

```
echo ' .'$_GET['function_name']().' B C D E F G';
```

The code is working fine, but I am just curious. Is `$_GET['function_name']()` ok? Is there any other way if this is a bad code? I did not want any security risk. Thank you guys!

Comment: Thank you guys! I really appreciate your replies. I was surprised to see your very fast responses..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes, it's allowed.

   a. Using a variable/string as a function-name is semi-common. If you'd like to test, try something like:

   ```
   <?php
   $function = 'print_r';
   $array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

   $function($array);
   ```

   It will work the same as if you're using `$_GET['function']()`; an example with arrays for additional clarity:

   ```
   <?php
   $user_data = array('function' => 'print_r');
   $values = array('one', 'two', 'three');

   $user_data['function']($values);
   ```
2. Yes, it's a very bad idea and one of the largest security risks you could possibly add to your site.

   a. Doing this will allow a user, or "attacker" if you want to think in security-sense, to execute any code they'd like on your server. Now, if you don't pass any user-controlled parameters to the function then they are obviously limited, however, they can still cause some damage.

   Let's take a worse-case scenario for instance:

   ```
   <?php

   $function = $_GET['function'];
   $parameter = $_GET['parameter'];

   $function($parameter);
   ```

   Now, what if I were to access this page via:

   ```
   www.example.com/page.php?function=exec&parameter=rm -rf %2f
   ```

   Albeit, you could do more (such as upload a backdoor), but I think this get's the point across =]

Comment: The first example used doesn't mirror the original question as well as it could, see http://ideone.com/dWRpbO (which "mirrors the problem" better - that is, the key is known but the *value* is supplied via $_GET - even though it's ultimately the same issue)

Comment: @user2864740 Actually, it mirrors it perfectly; `$_GET['function_name']` is the exact same as `$function` - they both contain a string that is the name of a function; My first example was simply demonstrating through simple variables (and not array-indexes) how strings can be used as function names. If you'd prefer me to update to show it as an array instead, I can easily do that as well (though the link you supplied has exactly that, as does my second example).

Comment: No, the first example misses the indirect. Thus it can't be "perfect". It shows indirection of a function call over *a* construct, but not over *the* (or rather, a mirroring) construct. PHP isn't exactly known for consistency.

Comment: @user2864740 I'm not sure I understand what you're getting at... I thought we were talking about using strings as function names (regardless of whether the string is stored in an array or a scalar)? If so, I think I made that point; otherwise, I may need you to further clarify. I just added a second example to the first that used the same code but with an array holding the function name instead (not sure if that's what you were after or not?)